# Сreate an adjacency matrix for image stitching

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

I have homographies built between pairs of images.  How do I create an adjacency matrix to describe which images overlap with each other?

Here my code. I call function 'match' to get homography between two images

```
a = s.left_list[0]
N = len(s.left_list)
adjacency_matrix = np.zeros((N, N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        for b in s.left_list[1:]:
            H = s.matcher_obj.match(a, b, 'left')
            print("Homography is : ", H)




def match(self, i1, i2, direction=None):
    imageSet1 = self.getSURFFeatures(i1)
    imageSet2 = self.getSURFFeatures(i2)
    print("Direction : ", direction)
    matches = self.flann.knnMatch(
        imageSet2['des'],
        imageSet1['des'],
        k=2
        )
    good = []
    for i , (m, n) in enumerate(matches):
        if m.distance < 0.9*n.distance:
            good.append((m.trainIdx, m.queryIdx))

    if len(good) > 4:
        pointsCurrent = imageSet2['kp']
        pointsPrevious = imageSet1['kp']

        matchedPointsCurrent = np.float32(
            [pointsCurrent[i].pt for (__, i) in good]
        )
        matchedPointsPrev = np.float32(
            [pointsPrevious[i].pt for (i, __) in good]
            )

        H, s = cv2.findHomography(matchedPointsCurrent,matchedPointsPrev, cv2.RANSAC, 4)
       return H

    return None

def getSURFFeatures(self, im):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    kp, des = self.surf.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
    return {'kp':kp, 'des':des}
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine which images overlap for stitching?  Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Yes, I have dataset of images for stitching. And I'm trying to determine which images overlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rephrase, you have a number of images and you want to determine which images overlap in order for you to put them into an image stitcher.

One of the most common ways is to simply iterate through every unique pair of images, then calculate the local homography between these two images.  Once you calculate the homography, you calculate the total fraction of keypoint pairs that were inliers for the homography.  If it's above some threshold, say 50%, then you would consider that there is a good amount of overlap between these two images and you'd count these as a valid pair.

The pseudocode for this is as follows, assuming your images are stored in some list `lst`:

```
N = len(lst)
adjacency_matrix = np.zeros((N, N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        1. Calculate homography between lst[i] and lst[j]
        2. Compute the total number of inlier keypoint pairs from the homography
        3. Take (2) and divide by the total number of keypoint pair matches
        4. If (3) is above a threshold (50% or 0.5), then:
            adjacency_matrix[i, j] = 1
            adjacency_matrix[j, i] = 1
```

Using the code you've just shown me, note that `cv2.findHomography` returns not only a matrix but a mask to tell you which pairs of points were used as inliers to build the matrix.  You can simply sum over the mask and divide by the total number of elements in this mask to give you that proportion.  This will only change the `return` statement of your code.  You've specified the reprojection threshold to be 4 pixels, which is quite large so you may get poor stitching results.  Make this smaller when you get this running.

```py
def match(self, i1, i2, direction=None):
    imageSet1 = self.getSURFFeatures(i1)
    imageSet2 = self.getSURFFeatures(i2)
    print("Direction : ", direction)
    matches = self.flann.knnMatch(
        imageSet2['des'],
        imageSet1['des'],
        k=2
        )
    good = []
    for i , (m, n) in enumerate(matches):
        if m.distance < 0.9*n.distance:
            good.append((m.trainIdx, m.queryIdx))

    if len(good) > 4:
        pointsCurrent = imageSet2['kp']
        pointsPrevious = imageSet1['kp']

        matchedPointsCurrent = np.float32(
            [pointsCurrent[i].pt for (__, i) in good]
        )
        matchedPointsPrev = np.float32(
            [pointsPrevious[i].pt for (i, __) in good]
            )

        H, s = cv2.findHomography(matchedPointsCurrent,matchedPointsPrev, cv2.RANSAC, 4)
        return H, sum(s) / len(s)  #  Change here

    return None
```

Finally, with the pseudocode here's what it is implemented with your particular setup:

```
lst = s.left_list
N = len(lst)
adjacency_matrix = np.zeros((N, N)) 
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        # 1. Calculate homography between lst[i] and lst[j]
        out = s.matcher_obj.match(lst[i], lst[j], 'left')

        # 2. Compute the total number of inlier keypoint pairs from the homography - done in (1)
        # 3. Take (2) and divide by the total number of keypoint pair matches - done in (1)

        # 4. If (3) is above a threshold (50% or 0.5), then:
        #    adjacency_matrix[i, j] = 1
        #    adjacency_matrix[j, i] = 1
        if out is not None:
            H, s = out
            if s >= 0.5:
                adjacency_matrix[i, j] = 1
                adjacency_matrix[j, i] = 1
```

Take note that your matching method outputs `None` if there are an insufficient number of inliers to provide confidence in a good homography.  Therefore we need to check if the output is not `None`, then check the proportion accordingly.  Finally, I would strongly recommend tuning the reprojection threshold and the similarity threshold (0.5 in the code just above) until you get a good enough stitch for your purposes.  These are baked into your code for the moment, but consider making these tunable.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't know how to compute total number of inlier keypoint pairs from the homography and total number of keypoint pair matches. I got homographies between pairs images. How I can get total number?

Comment: Do you have the keypoint matches from each of the homographies you calculated?  Simply put, for each of the source and target points you used to calculate the homography, you warp the source points with the homography and calculate the distance between the warped points and corresponding target points.  Any distances that are less than some threshold would be an lnlier.  The total number of inliers are the total number of distances that are less than this threshold.  This threshold is defined as the *reprojection error*.

Comment: Yes. I use SURF and KnnMatch. From this I got kp and des. 
I can't show my code, because  I can't post answer because of my low reputation :(

Comment: @Newman - Thanks.  I've edited my answer.